# Absence of Which in Non-restrictive clauses

Tags: non-restrictive, restrictive-participial-phrases

Is it necessary to place the ***which*** after the comma in the first two sentences (Non-restrictive clauses)?

1. The Nb thin films were deposited through HiPIMS with an industrial tool coating machine produced by CemeCon 8.0, ***displayed in Figure 8.***
2. The space between the two electrodes is filled with a process gas, ***typically an inert gas such as argon.***

***or***

3. The Nb thin films were deposited through HiPIMS with an industrial tool coating machine produced by CemeCon 8.0, ***which is displayed in Figure 8.***
4. The space between the two electrodes is filled with a process gas, ***which is typically an inert gas such as argon.***

Comment: Yes, if you wish to keep the comma. Otherwise no.

Comment: @user405662 I believe you're wrong, and sentences 1 and 2 are fine — and superior to 3 and 4.

Comment: @user405662 They're not. 1 and 2 are better than 3 and 4. Why that is should really go in the answer box, I suppose.

Comment: 1 and 2 are fine; they use what's known in traditional grammar as the "reduced relative clause" — where the relative pronoun and *be* verb are omitted.